# How to set maximum ID?

Tags: mysql

I can't find on internet answer to my simple question.
This is a problem:

```
------------------------
     ID  | Text
------------------------
      1  | Blaa
------------------------
```

And I wan't to set Maximum ID to value so you won't be able to reach higher than limit is.

Comment: This is an XY problem based on the wrong assumptions.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to set max ID"? Where?

Comment: @DHS: he wants to prevent someone to add entries to the DB with ID>a certain value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON table
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.ID <0 OR NEW.ID >50 THEN
    CALL `Error: Wrong value`; -- this trick will throw an error
  END IF;
END
```

**Bellow trigger is to limit number of rows in a table**

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_trigger_limit_rows
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON table
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF COUNT(*) < 0 OR COUNT(*) >50 THEN
    CALL `Error: Number of rows exceeded `; -- this trick will throw an error
  END IF;
END
```

[TRIGGERS DOC MYSQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: great @samitha,, 1up from me

Comment: whu you using for each, i coud'mnt understand it?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad `FOR EACH ROW`

Comment: Or can I count rows in Table? And do the same thing?

Comment: @VeeeneX Do you want to limit number of rows ?

Comment: Uhmm. And It require trigger?

Comment: As MySQL does not support a `check constraint`, you need a trigger for checking.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad A `FOR EACH ROW` triggered action executes once for each row that the triggering statement affects.If the triggering statement does not process any rows, a `FOR EACH ROW` triggered action does not execute.

Comment: in if you are checking which id the current insertion row id which will be added to the row?

Answer (score 0):

This would typically be handled in the application, not the database. When a user submits data, check to see if they've hit their limit before saving new ones. You might be able to engineer something with triggers, but it'd be convoluted and confusing to anyone else maintaining your system.

Comment: This would not typically be done in the application.  See the other answer.